# After Importing Spreadsheet to SharePoint, ID's don't match.

Tags: xml, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have imported a spreadsheet to a Sharepoint list. However, I have numbered my items and two numbers were missing #7 and #1054.  So this threw off my ID system. I was wondering how I can go about fixing this, because when someone adds another item. I want the next consecutive number. According to my system we have 1067 items, but the ID system has 1065 items, and when I add another item, the ID system goes into #1066, instead I want it to follow my system, so when I add an item. It goes to #1068. I am fairly new to Sharepoint and Infopath so please bear with me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The ID column is a incremental numeric like a Primary Key in a database table.  The only way to reset this is to delete the list and re-create it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the function for my custom selection. SO i have 1067 items. To the text field i added a formula max(Items)+1. and it worked!